# i want to get meta data of a audio file selected from my internal storage with intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-drawable, android-developer-api

i want to creat a app in which i select a song from my internal storage and its name ,artist name ,size will disply on text view how can i do this.
plese help !!!!!

[i tried this but its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOKCQ.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i want to fatch details of a song by selecting it from my mobile's internal storage using intant